# How can I resolve ECONNREFUSED error when connecting my Node.js app to MySQL database on cPanel?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, cpanel

I want to connect the database to my app before uploading my website to the host
but there is an error: connect ECONNREFUSED when i try to connect nodejs app to mysql database

I tried to connect it with mysql package for nodejs

Comment: The most likely cause is that MySQL Server is not running, or that there's no network route from your client to the database host. There's a manual page of further troubleshooting for that error here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

Comment: Should i use remote access in this situation?

Comment: I can't tell from your description if you are trying to connect to a MySQL Server instance on your localhost, or if you're trying to connect to your MySQL Server instance on your website. If the latter, then yes it needs to be remote access. But you first need to make sure you have a network route and it isn't being blocked by firewalls. Read the manual page I linked to.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.